# Passing param in URL to get json back in IOS

Tags: json, uitableview, ios7

Sorry i am really beginner in IPhone development,i am pulling json data from URL and its pulling and loading data perfectly in UITableView, below is code

```
- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/courses.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
    [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                    completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


         NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                     options:0
                                                                       error:nil];

         self.courses = jsonObject[@"courses"];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         });

     }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Now i want to add filter by instructors, Can any one tell me how i can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GET**

GET request is just a matter of appending query strings to the API url, for example:

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yourapiurl.com?id=%@","123";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:format];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
//Creating the data object that will hold the content of the URL
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

---

**POST**

```
-(NSData *)post:(NSString *)postParams{  
    //Build the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourapiurl.com"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postParams length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Send the Request
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    //Get the Result of Request
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return returnData;
}
```

usage:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"prop1=%@&prop2=%@&prop3=%@",
                                          "value1","value2","value3"];
NSData *JsonData = [self post :postString];
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
//then parse the JSON
```

Comment: I think i did not explain my question correctly, Actually on server i have method which take instructor as param and return data on the bases of that.So my problem is i do not know how to pass param on URL on server to get my filtered results. i am using web api.

Comment: are you asking how to do a POST/GET request to your API? @BraveBoy

Comment: yes, For Get request i have 1 method which requires id as param, and other is POST method which required request object as param having 3 properties to save. But i do not know how to pass params, your he;p will be highly appreciable.